# Stability of a nonhomogeneous system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-theory

I am analyzing the stability of the following differential equation system:
\begin{equation}
\left[\begin{array}{c}
\dot{x}_{1}\\
\dot{x}_{2}
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
-1 & 1\\
-1 & 1.5
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
x_{1}\\
x_{2}
\end{array}\right]+\left[\begin{array}{c}
9\\
9
\end{array}\right].
\end{equation}
The eigenvalues of the coefficient matrix are given as $-0.5$ and $1.$ Hence, the critical point given as $(9,0)$ is unstable.

Given the problem specific (initial) conditions that $x_1(0)=0$ and $\lim_{t\rightarrow\inf}x_1(t)x_2(t)=0$, I derive the solution as 
\begin{align}
x_{1}\left(t\right)&=9\left(1-e^{-\frac{t}{2}}\right)\\x_{2}\left(t\right)&=-4.5e^{-\frac{t}{2}}.
\end{align}

As $t$ tends to infinity, $x_1$ approaches to $9$, whereas $x_2$ approaches to $0.$ So, it seems to me that $(9,0)$ is a stable equilibrium.

I am not sure how a system with nonnegative eigenvalues would lead to a stable solution.

Comment: @Moo The critical point cannot be $(0,0)$ because at this point $\dot{x}_1$=$\dot{x}_2=9.$

Comment: No problem at all.

Comment: Well, as I state in the question, I completely understand that this saddle point needs to be unstable. However, using the initial conditions and identifying the actual solution, it turns out that the result is stable. That's the part I do not understand.

Comment: I guess I do not completely understand the concept of stability here. I thought for any initial condition, the system would either be unstable or stable. What you are saying is that the stability depends on the initial conditions?